# Python | Установка файла с github в нужный мне репозиторий

Tags: python, github, pip

как выполнить установку в моём случае `pip install git+https://github.com/LimeekBro/CMDPRO`
в нужный мне путь, к примеру E:\VCS

Comment: Что вообще такое «установка в репозиторий»? Pip занимается установкой пакетов в текущее Python-окружение и к репозиториям не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: репозиторий с путём перепутал

Comment: @andreymal в данном случае он скачивает репозиторий CMDPRO с файлами, но мне нужно поместить под один путь, зачем придиратся?

Comment: Это просто репозитрий с одним файлом, а не пакет, который можно установить через pip. Просто склонируйте репозиторий через git clone и работайте с ним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите клонировать в определённую папку, то вам следует:

1. Скачать [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) (чтобы убедиться, что вы скачали корректно, вам нужно ввести в консоль "git --version" и, если вы получили что-то похожее на "git version 2.36.1.windows.1", то тогда можете быть уверены, что вы всё делаете правильно).
2. Скопировать путь к репозиторию, для этого вам нужно кликнуть на зелёную кнопку "Code" и скопировать появившуюся ссылку.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Далее вы (с помощью консоли) заходите в папку, в которую вам нужно клонировать репозиторий (делается это с помощью cd <название_папки>.
4. После того как вы вошли в требуемую папку через консоль, вы должны прописать следующее - "git clone <ссылка_на_репозиторий>".

Для новичков я бы посоветовал приложение [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), оно куда проще для понимания, да и, наверняка, обучающего материала полно на YouTube. Удачи!